# iText pdf timestamp validation returns false, why?

Tags: java, validation, pdf, itext

Im using **iText 5.5.10** to validate timestamp in **pdf** file. Can someone explain me, why calling ***pkcs7.verifyTimestampImprint()*** method returns false?

Java code is from [iText 5 example site](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5),

see [C5_02_SignatureInfo.java](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter5/C5_02_SignatureInfo.java) as input file

use [testpdf_timestamp.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1skI3NM9cqw2m6eW9jKXaJXKzvCjyQMib/view).

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("testpdf_timestamp.pdf");
        AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
        ArrayList<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            System.out.println("===== " + name + " =====");
            System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + fields.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
            System.out.println("Document revision: " + fields.getRevision(name) + " of " + fields.getTotalRevisions());
            PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(name);
            System.out.println("Integrity check OK? " + pkcs7.verify());
            SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS");
            System.out.println("Signed on: " + date_format.format(pkcs7.getSignDate().getTime()));
            if (pkcs7.getTimeStampDate() != null) {
                System.out.println("TimeStamp: " + date_format.format(pkcs7.getTimeStampDate().getTime()));
                TimeStampToken ts = pkcs7.getTimeStampToken();
                System.out.println("TimeStamp service: " + ts.getTimeStampInfo().getTsa());
                // Why pkcs7.verifyTimestampImprint() returns FLASE?
                System.out.println("Timestamp verified? " + pkcs7.verifyTimestampImprint());
            }
        }
    }
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks for a response.

Comment: Please type here the code that is giving you trouble, not just include a link to it. Include just the relevant parts needed to help you. Cheers

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just edit your question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason

> why calling ***pkcs7.verifyTimestampImprint()*** method returns false

is that this method is meant for verifying the imprint of a *signature time stamp*, it is not meant for verifying the imprint of a *document time stamp*.

`PdfPKCS7` is a class for creating and verifying signatures and for requesting time stamps (for use as signature time stamps) and verifying time stamps (both signature and document). Thus, not all of its methods make sense in every use case. Unfortunately the `PdfPKCS7` JavaDocs don't make particularly clear which methods to use when.

In case of a document time stamp the verification of the timestamp imprint already takes place during the `verify` call.

---

You reference the code from `C5_02_SignatureInfo.java` on [this site](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-5) which clearly indicates that *"these examples were written in the context of the white paper [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](https://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig)."*

In that white paper you can see that the code you find in `C5_02_SignatureInfo.java` is from the chapter 5.2 "Retrieving information from a signature" and the time stamp verified by `verifyTimestampImprint()` is a signature time stamp.

For document time stamp validation you should look at the code in later chapters.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and white paper link. JavaDoc is unclear.